# How can I download Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Common.dll

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2015, tfs, reference

I am building an app in Visual Studio 2015 to allow people to see the changesets of a TFS server.

I found some an example code, however it requires a reference to Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Common.dll, but I couldn't find the DLL in the Reference Manager.

I have also searched the server which has TFS2015 installed, and I couldn't find there either.

Does anybody know where to find the dll?

Comment: I've one observation just in case it helps someone. `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client` namespace which was earlier present in `Microsoft TeamFoundation` DLL is now found in `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client` DLL. I'm using Visual Studio 2019.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be installed in your local development machine. If so then the dll (Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll) can be referenced by browsing for it.

Another solution is to install the Nuget package [Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client/14.89.0). Once installed, it will be ready to use for every project this package has been installed for.

Note: Be sure to check-in your packages folder if using version control.

> **Namespace:**  Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Common
>
> **Assembly:**
> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common (in
> Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll)

Source : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.framework.common.configfileexception(v=vs.120).aspx

Comment: ,I already have Microsoft.TeamFoundation..Client as reference but when I using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Common, it shows an error. Using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Client; is no problem. My version of  Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client is 14.0.0.0. Do I need to update it to get Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Common?

Comment: Sorry my mistake. You need to refer the Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll and try it again.

Comment: According to the MSDN link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.framework.common.configfileexception(v=vs.120).aspx  . There is no microsoft.teamfoundation.framework.common.dll .To use the class in Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Common , you just need to refer   **the Assembly** :  Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common (in Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll)