# Is there a way to list all TFS-workitems associated to change sets? Artifact class missing

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

I wrote a small program based on this article:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/narend/2006/08/07/programmatically-getting-workitems-associated-with-given-changsets-inverese-queries/

Now I have a machine where I have on VS-2019 installed. Rebuilding my project doesn't work because there are is a missing class Artifact in the code.

I just added the previous assemblies Microsoft.Teamfoundation.Client, Microsoft.Teamfoundation.Common, Microsoft.Teamfoundation.VersionControl.Client.

Or is there another way to list the workitems associated with the change sets?

Comment: In that link they mention "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.WorkItemTracking.Client.dll" Also that class could be in "Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll" but havent checked

Comment: Rechecked this. Mentioned, but not required. The namespaces used in the code are only using Microsoft.TeamFoundation;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Client;
using Microsoft.TeamFoundation.VersionControl.Client;

Comment: If the references you do include (Client) refer another assembly (Common), you must add a reference to that assembly also. Its not the first MS API I see that has a Client dll, a Server dll, and both require a Common dll.

Comment: Do look for a more recent article, that blog is from 2006 and VS2019 classes do no longer include the `Artifact` class.

Answer (score 0):

You must add the reference to the assembly it is defined in. According to [MS previous versions doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2013/bb165530(v=vs.120)) it is in the assembly `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll`

I have located `Artifact` class in assembly `Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll` in `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Common7\IDE\ReferenceAssemblies\v2.0\Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Common.dll` AKA VS2012 folder. Between 2012 and 2017 MS did remove it from that assembly.

Assuming your TFS is 2015, you can get it using [this NUGET package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client/14.89.0):

> Integrate with Team Foundation Server 2015 and Visual Studio Team Services from desktop-based, ASP.NET, and other Windows applications.  Provides access to version control, work item tracking, build, and more via public REST APIs.

Comment: Then intellisense should give you the advice of adding the `using Microsoft.TeamFoundation;` line. That is the namespace of the Artifact class. Consider adding a [mcve] 'cause it is getting messy

Comment: No. It tells me only to create it.

Comment: I am using the files from here: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\TeamFoundation\Team Explorer\

Comment: Then the reference you added does not contain that class, perhaps you are using code from a version and using references from another one? The link provided in the answer says that it is "an old API". Checking the dates that is... VS2012? And you are using VS2019

Comment: I have only 2017 on my machine. And in this version the class is also not present.

Comment: Go check nuget packages for up-to-date references, check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36454784/how-can-i-download-microsoft-teamfoundation-framework-common-dll)